# xamarin: Can we enable / disable localization inside the project

Tags: xamarin, localization

Hi I have to library which may need to use by two different project and one of the project require other languages whereas other require only english.

If i have AppResource include chinese and english on both libraries, the project only require english will have chinese if the device set to Chinese language.

Is there a way to enable or disable the localization in the project level.

Answer (score 0):

In the project that you only require English, you can set the CurrentCulture to English, so that the application will not read the language from the device, and will apply the English Language as default.

```
string culture="en-GB";


private void SetCulture(string culture)  //example => culture ="en-US", "de-DE", "ar-TN" ...
{
    CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCulture;
}
```

Comment: Where can i set this in.. Is my first time dealing with multi langauge. The AppResources, do we allow to have multiples version of AppResources. I mean i would like to have one language library which consist all libraries in one single place...

Comment: Firstly you can extend application class in xamarin android, then put these code in it. Please consider Android.App.Application class Constructor **Application(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)** https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Application/